# Is POSIX C networking / BSD socket APIs a supported API for Apple platfroms like iOS, iPadOS, tvOS?

Tags: ios, macos, tvos, watchos, ipados

We are writing a networking library that supports communication between endpoints on a proprietary protocol over UDP. We want to build that library not only for Apple Platforms but also other non-Apple platforms (like Windows, Linux, Android etc.) Considering this, one choice we have is to use POSIX C networking / BSD socket APIs.

One thing, which is NOT coming out clearly from Apple documentation is - can we use BSD sockets APIs and it work on most Apple platforms.

They do mention it won't work on watchOS 9 onwards. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3135-low-level-networking-on-watchos)

`The BSD sockets API doesn’t work for networking on watchOS under any circumstances. Use Network framework instead.`

BUT nowhere they mention that BSD sockets is one of the supported method in their latest documentation. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network).

Some archived documentation does say, it is a supported method. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html). BUT is it still supported, how would one know?.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what SwiftUI is about?

Comment: Not just from UI perspective. Say, i want to build a library which can be used by other developer to build apps for macOS, iOS, iPadOS, tvOS and watchOS. Say, that library is about building a proprietary protocol over standard protocols like HTTP, UDP and sockets system programming.

Comment: Might it have been germane to ask that _in the question?_ What you just said in your comment appears totally different from the question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.

Please refer to [this apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3151-choosing-the-right-networking-api):

It says:
Apple platforms have a wide range of networking APIs, spanning many different frameworks:

- Foundation,
- Network,
- BSD Sockets in the System framework,
- And more

If you’re working on watchOS, read [TN3135: Low-level networking on watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Technotes/tn3135-low-level-networking-on-watchOS) to understand its unique constraints.

Recommendations by Transport Layer protocols:

1. For both TCP and UDP you have two reasonable options: Network
   framework using `NWConnection` (Swift) or `nw_connection_t` (C-based
   languages) and BSD Sockets.
2. Network framework is by far the best choice. BSD Sockets is an acceptable choice if you have compatibility constraints, for example: When writing cross-platform code. Or When using an existing library that’s based on BSD Sockets.